# Both OS selections in startup boot into the same operating system

Tags: windows-7, boot

Currently I'm using my brother's laptop since mine went to the service. While starting up Windows Boot Manager screen shows me that I have two operating systems available (both Windows 7). I thought this might me caused by an windows.old folder in C drive. I checked and deleted this folder. Upon restarting I assumed I wouldn't be subjected to select an OS while booting and go directly to the "starting windows" screen now. To my surprise I was asked to select an OS again. I selected the second "Windows 7" option this time and the same OS booted up. Even though my laptop tells me that there are two OSs they both boot into the same thing. What do you think would cause this and how to remove this option?

I couldn't screenshot it so I'm adding this picture. In  my case both selections are Windows 7, not XP.

[image]

Edit: Boot tab of my msconfig page - http://prntscr.com/ljwjt6

Comment: Please provide the information from the Boot tab from your System Configuration (msconfig).  Edit your question to provide this vital information.  A screenshot of this information is necessary to answer your question.

Comment: I added the information you requested.

Comment: Since both entries point to the same installation you can delete the non-default entry.

Comment: You can also just set the timeout to something like 1 second if your uncomfortable with that solution.  I will submit an answer when I am at a pc

Comment: Did what you proposed and voila, the duplicate Win7 is gone and I'm booting right into Windows 7. Thank you. Post this as an answer and I'll accept.